# How do I flush previous printed line?

Tags: rust

I'm having a simple Rust program to emulate a timer:

```
use std::{io, thread, time};

fn main() {
    let start = time::Instant::now();
    let one_second = time::Duration::from_secs(1);
    let mut counter = 0;
    while counter <= 4 {
        thread::sleep(one_second);
        println!("ticking: {:.0}s", start.elapsed().as_secs_f32());
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
ticking: 1s
ticking: 2s
ticking: 3s
ticking: 4s
ticking: 5s
```

Now how do I change `println!` to erase the last printed line, so every time there is only one line showed in the terminal:

`ticking: 1s` at the 1st second

`ticking: 2s` at the 2nd second

...

then `ticking: 5s` only and no more other text in the end?

Comment: For me, this code prints out one line per second. Is that not what you want to happen?

Comment: @cdhowie I hope to see only 1 line every time (with previous line gone). Do I explain myself clear?

Comment: Does replacing `println!("ticking: {:.0}s", …);` with `print!("\rticking: {:.0}s", …); io::stdout().flush();` do what you want?

Comment: Oh, I missed the "erase the last line" part -- I interpreted the question to mean that the output wasn't being line-buffered, resulting in a dump of all lines at once after 5 seconds.

Comment: @Jmb `\r` seems to erase everything printed before. Can I erase only 1 line?

Comment: `\r` should only erase one line (in fact `\r` doesn't erase anything, it just moves the cursor back to the start of the line so that the rest of the string overwrites the last line).

Comment: @Jmb Exactly what I want!